# debian 9 init.d and systemd

Tags: debian, systemd, sysvinit

By default in Debian 9 systemd is the default. But I still see a lot of things under /etc/init.d directory. Does that mean I still can put things there to start up? Which directory (systemd or init.d) will be executed first?

Comment: The scripts in init.d will only be executed if there is no systemd-specific until file for that service.

Comment: so: all systemd service will be executed first; then init.d service which are not started from systemd, right? In another word, init.d still work fine in Debian 9, right?

Comment: The ordering will be a lot more complicated than that. init.d will work fine, but I would advise against using it.

Comment: ok. Some important packages I installed (nis, nfs) seem still putting service files under init.d instead of systemd.

Answer (score 4):

When `systemd` starts up, or when `systemctl daemon-reload` is run, `systemd` runs a `systemd-sysv-generator` program, which will make a list of `/etc/init.d` scripts and generate corresponding `.service` units for them unless a systemd-native `.service` unit already exists for them.

The generator will interpret any LSB header blocks in `init.d` scripts. They look like this:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          apache2
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# X-Interactive:     true
# Short-Description: Apache2 web server
# Description:       Start the web server
#  This script will start the apache2 web server.
### END INIT INFO
```

Any described dependencies (here `$local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named`) will be translated into corresponding systemd dependencies. Because there is not always a simple one-to-one mapping between `init.d` scripts and systemd services, some LSB dependencies like `$remote_fs`, `$network`, `$named`, `$portmap` and `$time` are specially mapped into corresponding systemd `.target` units by the generator.

The auto-generated wrapper services will simply run the corresponding `init.d` script. All the wrapper scripts are ordered to run after systemd `basic.target`, as soon as their dependencies allow. This makes the LSB headers rather important: if you're relying on the generator mechanism and your list of dependencies is incomplete, `systemd` is quite likely to attempt running your `init.d` script too soon, before the things it depends on are ready.

It's also possible that some packaged service has just one `init.d` script, but two or more systemd service files (think about NFS services for example). In such cases, the package will not rely on the generator, but instead will provide both the `init.d` script and the service files - with non-overlapping names. The package will also provide a symbolic link at `/lib/systemd/system/<name of init script>.service`, pointing to `/dev/null`. This makes `systemd` treat the service autogenerated from the init script as permanently masked, and the native unit files will handle the service process(es) instead.